# How to remove negative view? (Winkey + M not working)

Tags: 10.04, compiz

I just presses Winkey + m to see the change and now unable to revert to normal view as the same is not working , dunno why!!

I installed ccsm as suggested by my pal but unable to figure out how to remove the negative view. Some urgent help required. I'm using ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either open ccsm & disable the plugin or log out/in, things should return to normal
To go directly to plugin either in a terminal or Alt+F2 run box

```
ccsm -p neg
```

Note that there are 2 toggles - 1 for 'screen', 1 for 'window', they act independently